# create procedure in mysql use parameters

Tags: mysql

Please help me fix error with this code in mysql

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UpdateAccount (IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN AdisplayName VARCHAR(100),IN Apassword VARCHAR(100),IN AnewPassword VARCHAR(100))

BEGIN
    IN AisRightPass INT(0)

    SELECT AisRightPass = COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE USERName = AuserName AND PassWordL = Apassword;

    IF (AisRightPass =1)
    BEGIN
        IF (AnewPassword = NULL OR AnewPassword = '')
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE Account SET DisplayName = AdisplayName WHERE UserName = AuserName;
        END
        ELSE
            UPDATE Account SET DisplayName = AdisplayName, PassWordL = AnewPassword WHERE UserName = AuserName;
    END
    
END //
DELIMITER;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER//

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UpdateAccount (IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN Ad' at line 1

Comment: Which error ? Take some time to format your post using the "Edit" button EDIT : Thanks Michael :)

Comment: Welcome To SO! We are brilliant with code but cannot read minds. Please edit you question to let everyone know the exact error you receive and what your desired output is, thank you

Comment: You have tagged this as mysql, and the DELIMITER syntax looks like that of MySQL, but aspects of the procedure's internal syntax look more like MS SQL Server. What database system are you actually using, and where did this code originate?

Comment: As far as I know, `CREATE PROC` must be expressed as `CREATE PROCEDURE` in MySQL, and the `dbo.` is characteristic of SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you. I used sql now want to learn mysql but not to fix this error.

Comment: You will be facing several syntax errors. First, `DELIMITER//` should be expressed as `DELIMITER //` with a space between.  Then you will need to use `CREATE PROCEDURE`. The `dbo.`, unless your database is called `dbo`, are probably going to be faulty and should be removed.

Comment: Why can not use begin inside begin ? Michael Berkowski.

Comment: @LyTrung you can use `BEGIN/END` nested within `BEGIN/END` but you must terminate `END` as `END;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all! this is the correct code.

```
DELIMITER //
```

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_UpdateAccount(IN AuserName VARCHAR(100),IN AdisplayName VARCHAR(100),IN Apassword VARCHAR(100),IN AnewPassword VARCHAR(100))

BEGIN
DECLARE AisRightPass int(0);
    SELECT AisRightPass = COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE USERName = AuserName AND PassWordL = Apassword;

```
IF (AisRightPass =1) THEN
BEGIN
    IF (AnewPassword = NULL OR AnewPassword = '') THEN
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE Account SET DisplayName = AdisplayName WHERE UserName = AuserName;
    END;
    ELSE
        UPDATE Account SET DisplayName = AdisplayName, PassWordL = AnewPassword WHERE UserName = AuserName;
    end if;
END;
END IF;
```

END //
DELIMITER;